# I am getting the following error Project file could not be loaded _apacheCordovaProjectSourceItems.targets

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am getting the following Error when trying to include the project in my solution i am using visual studio 2015

[image: Error]

My Solution Explorer

[image: Solution Explorer]

And When I try to build and run the solution

[image]

My Visual Studio is installed on the abother Drive not c along with my android sdk.

Any Ideas?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it just reinstalled vs 2015